# Use HBase2.1.0 java api through Maven without class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2

Tags: java, maven, hbase

When I use maven to use HBase java api I can't import the class `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat2`.

But in `HBase2.1.0`'s javadoc there is `HFileOutputFormat2`: [`HBase2.1.0 javadoc`](https://hbase.apache.org/2.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/HFileOutputFormat2.html#configureIncrementalLoad-org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.TableDescriptor-org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionLocator-).

Then I tried directly adding `HBase2.1.0` lib to my project. That works without a problem.

Is this a Maven bug or am I using Maven in the wrong way?

Here is the HBase block in my maven file:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-mapreduce</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

---

From: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-mapreduce/2.1.0